# Username/password change, can I be scammed later?

Tags: bank-account, scams, online-banking

I gave my bank account log in and username along with security answers to someone. If I changed my username and password as well as my security questions, could I still be scammed later on?

Comment: The person to whom you gave the information might have already changed the password and security questions answers, making you appear to be the scammer.

Comment: If you use similar passwords for other accounts like email or facebook, you should change those as well.

Comment: @mkennedy Along the same lines, you should go through other accounts and change your security questions too, since the scammer has *those* and could use them to get into other accounts even without knowing the password there.

Answer (score 1):

It’s down to bank processes regarding such changes. Besides, the potential scammer may have your name, address, bank account numbers etc, not just your login details. They can bypass internet banking and try their luck at a physical branch.

If you’re concerned about this, ask the bank to close your bank (money) accounts and your internet-banking (login) account, and start again. Open new accounts and re-register for internet banking. Unless you have a lot of direct debits or direct credits, this shouldn’t be too much of a hassle for the sake of your peace of mind.

As @ceejayoz comments below, you can also do the ‘starting again’ part at a different bank to avoid any holdover whatsoever from the old accounts.

Comment: It *might* be worth doing this all at a *new* bank, too. Doing it at the same bank may open up some social engineering possibilities if the old, closed account is still somewhere in their systems. "Oh, I didn't mean to *close* that one..."

Comment: @ceejayoz Good point - thanks. I’ve edited to incorporate the idea.

Comment: I think this is over-panicking. Once you changed your password, you changed it. The old password is completely useless and no longer usable. If someone can walk in my bank and get access without my ID, only knowing an obsolete password, I would change the bank anyway.

Comment: @Aganju Internet banking isn't just an ID and password - it provides details to your bank accounts: name, address, bank account codes, balances and banking history, bank statements, and more. If the scammer got in, they could have acquired all that information, and would *still* have it even if you change your password. It's *that* information they can potentially misuse in the context of identity theft, whether at a branch or elsewhere.

Comment: _If_ they got in, your money is _gone_, and your password is _changed_. Why in the world should they bother collecting further info for later access if they already _have_ full access?

Comment: @Aganju All sorts of reasons. They might be phishing for someone related to the OP, they might be looking to acquire non-bank assets via identity theft, or simply playing the long game. I agree that closing accounts and changing banks is quite a step to take, but they are pretty simple steps in the scheme of things when the OP is after peace of mind.